# Connect operator is confusing, elements with different keys are unexpectly paired In ConnectedStreams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Keyed-streams smokeLevelStream and sensorReadingStream have different keys, but the outputs show record of key="1" from sensorReadingStream and record of key="10" from smokeLevelStream
goes to the same `CoFlatMapFunction`.

Operator `connect` is confusing.

Part of outputs:

```
6> sensor_1 is low = 1.0
6> somke_coming = HIGH
...
6> sensor_1 is high = 1.0
```

Source code:

```java
public class ConnectTrans {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataStream<SensorReading> sensorReadingStream = env.addSource(new SensorSource()).setParallelism(1).keyBy((KeySelector<SensorReading, String>) value -> value.id);
        DataStream<SmokeLevel> smokeLevelStream = env.addSource(new SmokeLevelSource()).setParallelism(1).keyBy((KeySelector<SmokeLevel, String>) value -> value == SmokeLevel.HIGH ? "10" : "9");
        ConnectedStreams<SensorReading, SmokeLevel> connDataSource = sensorReadingStream.connect(smokeLevelStream);
        connDataSource.flatMap(new AlertCoFlatMap()).print();
        env.execute("test");
    }
}
class AlertCoFlatMap implements CoFlatMapFunction<SensorReading, SmokeLevel, String> {

    private SmokeLevel smokeLevel = SmokeLevel.LOW;

    @Override
    public void flatMap1(SensorReading value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        if (smokeLevel == SmokeLevel.HIGH && value.temperature > 0) {
            out.collect("sensor_" + value.id + " is high = " + value.temperature);
        } else {
            out.collect("sensor_" + value.id + " is low = " + value.temperature);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(SmokeLevel value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        out.collect("somke_coming = " + value);
        this.smokeLevel = value;
    }
}
```

```java
public class SensorSource implements SourceFunction<SensorReading> {

    private boolean running = true;

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<SensorReading> ctx) throws Exception {
        while(true) {
            ctx.collect(new SensorReading("1", 100, 1));
            Thread.sleep(100);
            ctx.collect(new SensorReading("2", 102, 2));
            Thread.sleep(100);
            ctx.collect(new SensorReading("3", 103, 3));
            Thread.sleep(100);
            ctx.collect(new SensorReading("4", 104, 4));
            Thread.sleep(100);
            ctx.collect(new SensorReading("5", 105, 5));
            Thread.sleep(100);
            ctx.collect(new SensorReading("6", 106, 6));
        }
    }

    /** Cancels this SourceFunction. */
    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        this.running = false;
    }
}
```

```java
public class SmokeLevelSource implements SourceFunction<SmokeLevel> {

    // flag indicating whether source is still running
    private boolean running = true;

    /**
     * Continuously emit one smoke level event per second.
     */
    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<SmokeLevel> ctx) throws Exception {
        while(true) {
            ctx.collect(SmokeLevel.HIGH);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            ctx.collect(SmokeLevel.LOW);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        this.running = false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you connect two keyed streams (or key a connected stream) and process the result with a CoFlatMap, this means that records from one stream will trigger the flatmap1 callback, and records from the other stream will trigger the flatmap2 callback, AND that all records with the same key (regardless of which stream they are in) will be sent to the same instance of the CoFlatMap operator.

This is the basis for implementing operations like joins. E.g., imagine joining a stream of transactions (t_id, t_customer_id, t_amount) with a stream of customer records (c_id, c_name) on t_customer_id == c_id. You'll want to key the transaction stream on t_customer_id, and the customer stream on c_id -- so that all records for a specific customer are processed by the same instance of the join operator.

For this reason, it is crucial that both streams are mapped onto the same key space.

The reason your code isn't working as expected is that you've used a private member variable to store the smokeLevel. An instance of the CoFlatMap is multiplexed across all records for all of the keys assigned to that parallel instance (rather than having a separate instance per key). What you should do instead is to use key-partitioned `ValueState` to store the smokeLevel. Then there will be a separate smokeLevel per key, and the state will be checkpointed and restored (and rescaled, if necessary).

Comment: So, all senarios that process data based on keyed partition should use key-state to store keyed-related records, all right?Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, that's right. The Flink docs include a tutorial on this subject: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/learn-flink/etl/#stateful-transformations

Comment: And for an example that uses a RichCoFlatMapFunction with keyed state, see the exercise that goes with that tutorial: https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares